# Entity Migration. Could not drop constraint. See previous errors

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

Here is the code that produce this error. I've tried solution for renaming the `AddForeignKey` but the error is same.

> 'PK_dbo.Item' is not a constraint.
>   Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.

Can you suggest some solution?

```
public override void Up()
{
    DropForeignKey("dbo.AddGallery", "item_fk_id", "dbo.Item");
    DropForeignKey("dbo.ExtraFieldValue", "item_fk_id", "dbo.Item");
    DropPrimaryKey("dbo.Item");
    AddColumn("dbo.Item", "id", c => c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true));
    AddPrimaryKey("dbo.Item", "id");
    AddForeignKey("dbo.AddGallery", "item_fk_id", "dbo.Item", "id");
    AddForeignKey("dbo.ExtraFieldValue", "item_fk_id", "dbo.Item", "id");
    DropColumn("dbo.Item", "item_id");
}

public override void Down()
{
    AddColumn("dbo.Item", "item_id", c => c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true));
    DropForeignKey("dbo.ExtraFieldValue", "item_fk_id", "dbo.Item");
    DropForeignKey("dbo.AddGallery", "item_fk_id", "dbo.Item");
    DropPrimaryKey("dbo.Item");
    DropColumn("dbo.Item", "id");
    AddPrimaryKey("dbo.Item", "item_id");
    AddForeignKey("dbo.ExtraFieldValue", "item_fk_id", "dbo.Item", "id");
    AddForeignKey("dbo.AddGallery", "item_fk_id", "dbo.Item", "id");
}
```

Comment: Run desc Item. What do you see?

Comment: Do you have that primary key in the schema?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the primary key no longer exists and this is why it cannot be dropped.

Comment: I am trying to change property name of the primary key. Is that possible when foreign keys exist ?

Answer (score 0):

I find an solution for this problem. Because I've trying to change the name of the existing primary key name, I encountered an error while migration because that primary key was referenced to other tables. So the solution was simply to add **[Column("id")]** DataAnnotation and than make the migration. Column name of the primary key was successfully changed without any error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used "Code first from database" approach. I had DB with my own foreign/primary key names different from ones the migration expects. So the migration just couldn't find relationships with such names. I had to explicitly name these relationships in dropping:

```
DropForeignKey(string dependentTable, string name);
DropPrimaryKey(string table, string name);
```

But be aware: using this approach, you need to explicitly modify Up and Down methods. It means, if you don't redefine Down() to match new Up method (using the previous FK/PK names) then if you go back on migrations, initial Down() will produce keys with its own names and Up() will need to have initial structure before self modifying, unless it won't find keys with such names when you use update-database again.